# I got this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input; What is wrong with my cookie creating code?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I am currently trying to create a cookie storing and making program. I got this base code from the internet but I am currently trying to adjust it to my liking. I thought my code was complete but when i ran it, I get this error. This is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="myform" action="">
         Enter name: <input type="text" name="customer" value= "hello"/>
         <button type="name" onclick= "WriteCookie()">Login</button>
      </form>
       <form name="myform" action="">
         <p> click the following button and see the result:</p>
         <button type="GetCookies" onclick= "ReadCookie()">Get Cookies</button>
      </form>
   <script>
      function WriteCookie()
      {
        cookievalue= "hello";
        document.cookie = cookievalue;
        document.write ("Setting Cookies : " + "name=" + cookievalue );
      }
      function ReadCookie()
            {
               var allcookies = document.cookie;
               document.write ("All Cookies : " + allcookies );
               
               // Get all the cookies pairs in an array
               cookiearray = allcookies.split(';');
               
               // Now take key value pair out of this array
               /*for(var i=0; i<cookiearray.length; i++){
                  name = cookiearray[i].split('=')[0];
                  value = cookiearray[i].split('=')[1];
                  document.write ("Key is : " + name + " and Value is : " + value);
               }
            } */

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am a beginner in HTML5 programming with no prior knowledge of Javascript (no that would be useful) Im only 12 (not to make excuses) so please try to explain it in the simplest way possible, thanks.

Comment: You comment block end in wrong place, so your `ReadCookie` function is not closed. Move `*/` before last `}`

Comment: The closing } is commented

Answer (score 1):

You have the end of one of your comments on the wrong line:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="myform" action="">
         Enter name: <input type="text" name="customer" value= "hello"/>
         <button type="name" onclick= "WriteCookie()">Login</button>
      </form>
       <form name="myform" action="">
         <p> click the following button and see the result:</p>
         <button type="GetCookies" onclick= "ReadCookie()">Get Cookies</button>
      </form>
   <script>
      function WriteCookie()
      {
        cookievalue= "hello";
        document.cookie = cookievalue;
        document.write ("Setting Cookies : " + "name=" + cookievalue );
      }
      function ReadCookie()
            {
               var allcookies = document.cookie;
               document.write ("All Cookies : " + allcookies );
               
               // Get all the cookies pairs in an array
               cookiearray = allcookies.split(';');
               
               // Now take key value pair out of this array
               /*for(var i=0; i<cookiearray.length; i++){
                  name = cookiearray[i].split('=')[0];
                  value = cookiearray[i].split('=')[1];
                  document.write ("Key is : " + name + " and Value is : " + value);
               } */
            }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```